# combining two folders of excel file into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two folders in each of them I have 10 .csv files how can I combine these two into one data frame? in first folder my data is as below:

```
T1           T2        s
1.00001   5.00001    going out
```

the second folder is the same:

```
t1        t2       R
1.00001  5.00001   5
```

I WANT TO COMBINE as below:

```
  T1         T2         s         R
1.00001  5.00001  going out      5
```

Comment: And what have you come up with so far?

Comment: use `glob` to get a list of file paths then use list comprehension to read the files into a `DataFrame`. After that you can use `pd.concat`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

result = df1.merge(df2, lef_on=['T1','T2'], right_on=['t1','t2'], how='inner')
```

Use pandas merge function. It is equivalent of sql join.